# Doing a conditional Diff() with several conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been wrangling with a particular set of data lately. It's quite easily done with Excel, through Pivot Tables, but I'd like to learn to do it with R in a repeatable fashion.
I am trying to build an electricity generation stack (ERCOT), with a graph at the end showing how electric generation capacity in MW (QSECurveMW) varies function of price levels (QSECurvePrice), ResourceName, ResourceStatus, ResourceType and QSECurveNum.

It works this way:
For each price level (QSECurvePrice), power producers (ResourceType) dispatch a certain production capacity (QSECurveMW), each additional capacity is signaled by QSECurveNum. Resources are flagged with a certain ResourceStatus. Resources calls are redistributed every 15 min (4 times per hour), hence producers are supposed to give 4 prices per hour (that I flagged using the "timing" column).

[edit]
I applied a diff1 function

```
  db15 <- db15 %>%
      group_by(timing,ResourceName) %>%
      mutate("diff1" = QSECurveMW-lag(QSECurveMW))
```

Afterwards, I tried to add them through a cumsum function

```
    db15 <- db15 %>%
  group_by(timing) %>%
  mutate("addition" =cumsum(db15$diff1) )
```

but an error message appears:

```
Error: Column `addition` must be length 2942 (the group size) or one, not 11806
```

The variable "timing" can take 4 possible values: q1,q2,q3,q4. Reflecting the frequency of the energy supply bidding intervals per hour each company tenders to ERCOT (4 per hour, every 15min). Hence, for any given interval of 15 min, there is at that date 2942 different MW values.
In my case, for some reason, the cumsum function here only did the cumulative sum for diff1 tagged with a "timing" of q1.

Data base:

```
    > head(dbexample)
                     time     ResourceName ResourceType QSECurveNum QSECurveMW QSECurvePrice OutputSchdl ResourceStatus BasePoint hour day minutes timing diff1
1 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG1        HYDRO           1          0       -250.00          33           ONOS        30   15   3       0     q1     0
2 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG1        HYDRO           2         28       -250.00          33           ONOS        30   15   3       0     q1    28
3 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG1        HYDRO           3         33       -249.99          33           ONOS        30   15   3       0     q1     5
4 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG1        HYDRO           4         33       3000.00          33           ONOS        30   15   3       0     q1     0
5 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG2        HYDRO           1          0       -250.00          33           ONOS        31   15   3       0     q1     0
6 2011-08-03 15:00:18.000 AMISTAD_AMISTAG2        HYDRO           2         29       -250.00          33           ONOS        31   15   3       0     q1    29
```

Excel rendering of the analysis using pivot tables, in any given interval of 15 min (q1 to q4). I would like to obtain an analog graph with R.
Here x=Addition (cumulative sum of energy supply in MW)
y= price in $ per MW. See how the higher the energy supply, the higher the price, showing how in situations of very high pressure on the energy network (peaks) prices spike.

[image: Excel rendering of the analysis using pivot tables, in any given interval of 15 min (q1 to q4). I would like to obtain an analog graph with R]

Comment: There is a column 'diff2' and your code for `rowsum` is `rowsum(db15$diff1,db15$cumsummer)`

Comment: Edited thanks for the headsup

Comment: I tried your example from the `head`, it is working fine.  Can you show the `dput` of a small example that is not working `rowsum(c(NA, 28, 61, 66, NA, 29), c(0, 28, 61, 94, 94, 123))`

Comment: Hello, 
Please check the new edit, I changed the code a bit. 
The length seems to be the problem, the cumsum function only sums the rows that have the Timing variable take the value "q1" for some reason. Which is why I have the error message. 
However, my approach seems to be wrong, as when I try to do the graph (x=QSECurveMW, y=addition), it shows me several possible values for each price. 
I think this calls for a pivottable and an ordering of the prices and the total available capacity corresponding to that price. How do you think I could tackle that?